# phpmailer com gmail

Tags: php, html, email

Olá, estou tentando enviar e-mail com o PHP mailer... Porém está dando erro...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Experimente\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line
>   2807

Já tentei várias vezes usar esta função de enviar e-mail e sempre dá erro. Alguém sabe como eu conserto isto?

Sei que tem outras postagens com o PHPMAILER mas o meu se difere por ser um erro que é diferente em todas outras postagens.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$Vai = "exemplo de texto a enviar";
echo "a";
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
echo "b";
define('GUSER', 'mygmail@gmail.com');  // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'mypassword');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}
echo "c";
if (smtpmailer('felipejorgetop@gmail.com', 'felipejorgetop@gmail.com', 'Felipe Jorge Sales da Silva', 'Assunto do Email', $Vai)) {
    echo "email enviado com sucesso";
    Header("location:http://www.dominio.com.br/obrigado.html"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.
}

if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
echo "não enviado";
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa mostar a linha do erro ou a anterior. É um erro de sintaxe. Evite usar bibliotecas legadas(sem atualizações) ou de qualidade duvidosa.

Comment: Esse erro mostra uma linha... Você pode postar essa linha e as duas anteriores e posteriores aqui por favor?

Comment: Eu fiz download do PHPmailer... Esta linha não fui eu que fiz.
Eu so fiz oq está no código ai, o resto é pasta padrão do PHP mailer

Comment: Esse erro não deveria existir, você pode baixar a versão recente e ver se funciona sem esse 'bug', não esqueça de verificar os requisitos dela como por exemplo versão do php ou editar a pergunta e adicionar a linha do erro(2807) e a anterior.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem da linha que dá erro....

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem com a linha que está dando erro... Se puder me ajudar ou mandar uma biblioteca que funcione eu agradeço. Pois esta está difícil...

Comment: Eu não consigo ver a imagem xD

Comment: É só clicar na imagem que ela dá zoom

Comment: O dominio dela é bloqueado(proxy), por isso não consigo ver.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xm2FP.png bloqueado ai na sua empresa?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33285/discussion-between-felipe-jorge-and-rray).

Comment: Já tentei baixar vário códigos  do Github, mas não funcionam corretamente... Cada um dá um erro.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Já tentou testar isso online e não localmente?

Comment: Já sim, o erro de sintaxe dá online e não localmente. Localmente não dá erro de sintaxe.